# Is there an optimal/efficient way to compare multiple rows for similarity/difference?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I am trying to compare a list of values to another - the objective is to work out total difference/similarity between Items, and grade the Items with how similar they are to each other along several Criteria, which is measured as a swing from the default (0).

The Criteria value only ever varies between -8 and +8 (or NULL if not specified).  So for example:

```
        Colour:     Flavour:    Temperature:
Item A:     -4              2               5
Item B:     3               0               3 
Item C:     2               -3              1
```

So to work out the difference between Items A and C: Colour (2 - -4) = -6, flavour (-3 - 2) = -5, and temperature (1 - 5)=-4. So -6 + -5 + -4 = gives a Score of 15. Assume ABS() is used to standardise the differences before getting the Item total / Score.  I'll simplify the problem a bit by leaving off some of the maths - the main issue here is to get that Score, and the number of criteria matched, for each row.

Please give the problem some thought before looking at my current solution, to avoid preconceptions: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/11c0f/1

Is there a nicer way of doing it, which I'm ignorant of?  Potentially there could be around 150 Criteria, and up to a few hundred Items/rows needing to be displayed and sorted by their Similarity to each other, which would be quite a bit of crunching.

Caching the results of these expensive queries is a given. This question is more about the difference/similarity calculation itself - is there some deep SQL magic that could do the actual comparison more efficiently than using pure arithmetic? The data could be stored another way for ease of processing if need be.

There is a catch also - not all Items will always have all Criteria, the field would be NULL if none was applicable.

I've deliberately omitted any SQL from the body of this question to avoid precolouring viewers opinions. I'm currently using MySQL but if another system offers an efficient way to handle this then that is entirely changeable.

Thanks in advance for your experience and insights.

Comment: I don't see how your arithmetic solution does what you want.  Values of 0 could be identical values -- which would seem very similar -- or negatives and positives offsetting each other.

Comment: If by saying "Potentially there could be around 150 criteria" you're implying that you may have 150 attribute columns in your current design, then one important improvement you could make would be to restructure your table to have three columns: item, attribute (e.g., color, flavor, temperature), and value.

Comment: Gordon: A good spot, I'd not noticed that. I'll edit the question once I've taken account of it.

Comment: I'll make a fully normalised sql fiddle - I'll edit the question when done.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - I've updated the question with a fiddle, and simplified and corrected the actual maths part. A sample 'database' and my current solution is present in the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Consider encapsulating your similarity calculation into function that takes two arguments.  Assuming this function is named `similarity()` then a possible solution would be:

```
select
    item_1,
    item_2,
    sum(sim) as similarity
from
    (
    select
        a.item_name as item_1,
        b.item_name as item_2,
        similarity(a.criteria_value, b.criteria_value) as sim
    from
        ourdata as a
        inner join ourdata as b
            on b.item_name > a.item_name and b.attribute_name = a.attribute_name
     ) as x
 group by
     item_1,
     item_2;
```

If appropriate, you could run this on your `items_attributes` table instead of the `ourdata` table--it's not clear to me why they have different numbers of rows.

Comment: The ourdata table is a 'view' if you will of what the query pulls from the normalised data. It's for sanity when testing, to prevent nested spaghetti subqueries.

The similarity calculation looks at the values of all criteria for a given row/item, depending which table you use to play with.  You cannot just give it two criteria and get the whole result. To compare between criteria, you just ABS(a - b) to find the difference.

Assuming I'm understanding your suggestion correctly that is?

Comment: Comments are far too short! Firstly, thanks for assisting.  The first query in the fiddle shows you how the ourdata table is created. If you prefer to use the original data then you're obligated to use subqueries to get at it, as with my original solutions, which complicates matters.  I'm playing with your SQL now - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/11c0f/12 . It looks like it compares everything to everything else? When using the _full table, which includes the non-paired Criteria, it fails.  The example in the fiddle shows one selected row, compared to others specified by ID (for testing sanity). 1/2

Comment: The sqlfiddle is useful to provide some data to test with, but the value of the queries it contains is unclear because you're asking for a simpler approach.  Your problem description says "-6 + -5 + -4 = gives a Score of 15" -- In the code above, the summing shown in that snippet is done with the sum() aggregate function on line 4, and perhaps the `similarity()` function need be nothing more than `abs(a.criteria_value - b.criteria_value).

Comment: 2/2 I apologise if the question was unclear, this is why I added the fiddle and working example query.  The objective is to test one Item, against all others specified (which in this case is the rest of the table).  If it helps I can add more example data?

Comment: Okay, I've done some more work; http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/11c0f/23  Your example is the final query. When it uses the inferred data, rather than the table, surprisingly, it's actually less efficient than my original solution - the first stage uses 2145 rows rather than 2001. Please note that I limited it to one comparison row and added the count!

Comment: It would likely be more efficient if you ran the similarity calculation on the `items_attributes` table and joined that result with the `items` and `attributes` tables to convert IDs to names.